# ImageButton: Mipmap source image not stretching to fill button

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, user-interface

I have an ImageButton that is the child to a RelativeLayout that uses a mipmap resource for it's source. However I'm having an issue with the mipmap stretching to fill the ImageButton.

In all of the threads I've read people have recommended "android:scaleType="fitXY"" yet this does not seem to work for me. The XML is listed below.

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="330dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/search_edit_text"
        android:layout_width="280dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:hint="@string/search_hint"
        android:background="#EAEAEA"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:layout_margin="0dp"
        android:textColorHint="#C9C9C9"/>

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/search_edit_text"
        android:layout_margin="0dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:padding="0dp"
        android:stateListAnimator="@null"
        android:src="@mipmap/search_button_icon"
        android:background="@null"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

The image below is the result of the above XML, however the search button (to the right of the edittext element) should be the same height, and be attached to the edittext.

[image: search bar]

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just copy/pasted your code, and the image below is what I get (I used default `android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"`)

And I get a visual similar to yours.

[image]

Where it looks like the image isn't "stretching"

[image]

However if you click on the image you see that image's boarder perfect matches the EditText to its Left.

So my guess is that your input Image 'search_button_icon' Has built in padding in the Image itself and would need to be cropped if you want it to be 'exact' visually as the EditText.

Comment: yes you're correct. to correct this I added a background color to fill the rest of the imagebutton in. thanks for the reply, I'll accept your answer